# Why can I use .equalsIgnoreCase("anoterString") without assigning it to a variable or within a control flow statement?

Tags: java

I came across this code:

```
    for (final String s : myList)
    {
        s.equalsIgnoreCase(test);
        updateNeeded = true;
        break;              
    }
```

I suspect that this is not what the programmer actually wanted to do. I believe he meant to write something like:

```
    for (final String s : myList)
    {
        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(test))
        {
            updateNeeded = true;
                break;
        }   
    }
```

However, I don't understand why there is no error in the first code snippet.

```
 s.equalsIgnoreCase(test);
```

since the method .equalsIgnoreCase("anoterString") returns a boolean and it is not being assigned to anything or used within a control flow statement

Comment: You are not forced to assign return values.

Comment: It is not neccessary to assign a returned value, if you don't need it for future use.

Comment: @Michael, I was obviously looking at the second snippet.  Not that any of this subject deserves a 'reference'....or anywhere near this amount of discussion, for that matter.

Comment: I deleted the comment.  Now this thread will be even more confusing. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a method call. You don't *have* to use the result of a method call for anything else.

It's *rarely* a good idea to ignore the result of a non-void method (in particular, the return value of `InputStream.read` is sometimes ignored when it really shouldn't be) but the language specification makes no attempt to call this out as a problem.

Answer (score 2):

It should probably meant to be as you think. You can call a method and not assigning its result, as sometimes you just don't need the result.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, this is probably an error. However, Java compiler has no way of knowing that `equalsIgnoreCase` method is a "pure function", i.e. produces no side effects and is otherwise meaningless unless you keep its return value.

Comment: In principle it probably could (if the function called uses only local variables, for example), but why bother with such heuristics and risk tripping some edge case? Like Ben and Binyamin Sharet say, sometimes you just don't care about the return value, and that should be the programmer's perogative. Probably a mistake in this case, maybe not so in others.

Answer (score 1):

Most programming languages allow you to ignore the returned code of a method.
There are times that you would not care about the returned value and in these cases you should be allowed to.